# Proof that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing in $x$ when $f$ has increasing returns to scale.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $f(x):(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}_+$, increasing and differentiable, and
> consider the ratio $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$. I want to show that if $f$
> has increasing returns to scale ($f(\lambda x)>\lambda f(x)$ for any
> $\lambda>1$) then $g'(x)>0$, and if $f$ has decreasing returns to
> scale ($f(\lambda x)<\lambda f(x)$ for any $\lambda>1$), then
> $g'(x)<0$.

This seems intuitive to me, as under increasing returns to
scale, the numerator of $g$ grows more than linearly, while under decreasing
returns to scale, it grows less than linearly. However, I'm having
trouble with the formal proof. Here's my attempt:

Let $f$ have increasing returns to scale. Then, $g(\lambda x)=\frac{f(\lambda x)}{\lambda x}>\frac{f(x)}{x}=g(x)$ for any $\lambda>1$. Consider the continuous invertible transformation defined by $\lambda x=x+h$, so that $h=(\lambda-1)x$. Then, we can write

$$g'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=\lim_{\lambda\to 1^+}\frac{g(\lambda x)-g(x)}{(\lambda-1)x}>\lim_{\lambda\to 1^+}\frac{g(x)-g(x)}{(\lambda-1)x}=0,$$

so that $g'(x)>0$. I take the limit from the right because $g$ is differentiable and the limit from the right and left must coincide. What tells me there's something wrong with my proof is taking the limit from the left:

$$g'(x)= \lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=\lim_{\lambda\to 1^-}\frac{g(\lambda x)-g(x)}{(\lambda-1)x}<\lim_{\lambda\to 1^-}\frac{g(x)-g(x)}{(\lambda-1)x}=0,$$

where the denominator is negative if $\lambda\to 1^-$, which flips the inequality. Any help spotting the mistake or coming up with a proof of this statement is greatly appreciated.

**Update/Answer:** As the answer below by @EtienneBfx indirectly points out, increasing returns to scale apply for $\lambda>1$, so that the inequality in the limit from the right applies ($\lambda>1$), but not the inequality in the limit from the left $(\lambda<1)$. That eliminates the contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $\forall \lambda > 0$, $g(\lambda x) \geq g(x)$ then you have $g(x)=g(x*1) \geq g(1)$ and $g(1)=g(x*\frac{1}{x}) \geq g(x)$.

So I guess that $g$ is a constant fonction. If the inequality are stricts there is no solution!

Maybe the exercice is with $\lambda > 1$...

Comment: You are absolutely right: your post made me realize the answer. My mistake is taking $\lambda>0$. The definition of returns to scale is for $\lambda>1$. That implies that only the limit from the right is relevant in my calculations, because the inequality $f(\lambda x)>\lambda f(x)$ is only true for $\lambda>1$, i.e. , when $\lambda\to 1^+$.